# How to add more conditions to a Laravel Relation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have a 'connections' table with the following schema:

```
id 
requestor_id (user_id)
requested_id (user_id)
```

Let's say John Doe (requestor) connects to Jane Doe (requested) and Jonnie Doe (requestor) connects to John Doe (requested). To list all John Doe's connections I would have to

```
inner join "connections" 
  on "users"."id" = "connections"."requested_id" 
  or "users"."id" = "connections"."requestor_id"
```

But this is not currently possible in Laravel, because, afaik, there's is no `BelongsToMany->or()` method, so how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to hack the Relation and came out with a temporary solution:

```
public function connections()
{
    $relation = $this
        ->belongsToMany(static::class, 'connections', 'requestor_id', 'requested_id')
        ->withTimestamps();

    /// delete the already built inner join
    $relation
        ->getQuery() // Eloquent\Builder
        ->getQuery() // Query\Builder
        ->joins = [];

    /// create a new inner join with the needed or condition
    $relation->getQuery()->getQuery()->join('connections', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('users.id','=','connections.requestor_id');
        $join->orOn('users.id','=','connections.requested_id');
    });

    return $relation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to fix that solution, because it won't return correct results (**check below**).
Secondly, **it won't work with eager loading**, so I wouldn't use that.

That being said, you can create custom relation that extends `BelongsToMany` and adjust relation method on the model, or use what's already there.

So let me first suggest something, that I find a better way (I will use friends not connections, to make it easier to follow):

```
// friendship that I started
function friendsOfMine()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}

// friendship that I was invited to 
function friendOf()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}

public function getFriendsAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('friends', $this->relations)) $this->loadFriends();

    return $this->getRelation('friends');
}

protected function loadFriends()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('friends', $this->relations))
    {
        $friends = $this->mergeFriends();

        $this->setRelation('friends', $friends);
    }
}

protected function mergeFriends()
{
    return $this->friendsOfMine->merge($this->friendOf);
}
```

Now it's pretty easy to use, flexible, and allows eager loading:

```
$user = User::first();

$user->friends; // merged collection thanks to the accessor

$user->friendOf; // collection of my fans ;)

$user->friendsOfMine; // my idols

$users = User::with('friendOf', 'friendsOfMine')->get();
```

---

### **Fixed solution of yours**

The problem is, there will still be `where` clause, that will break your query. So instead you need to move it to the `joinClause` and add one more there:

```
public function friends()
{
    $relation = $this
        ->belongsToMany(static::class, 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id')
        ->withTimestamps();

    // get underlying Query\Builder
    $query = $relation->getQuery()->getQuery();

    // get rid of wrong where and its bindings
    $query->setBindings([])
    $query->wheres = [];

    // fetch and alter joinClause
    $join = reset($query->joins);
    $join->where('friends.user_id', '=', $this->getKey())
        ->orOn('users.id','=','friends.user_id')
        ->where('friends.friend_id', '=', $this->getKey());


  // Now the join looks like this:
  //
  // $key = $this->getKey();
  //
  // $query->join('friends', function($join) use ($key)
  // {
  //   $join->on('users.id', '=', 'friends.friend_id')
  //       ->where('friends.user_id', '=', $key)
  //      ->orOn('users.id', '=','friends.user_id')
  //       ->where('friends.friend_id', '=', $key);
  // });

    return $relation;   
}
```